# asp.net identity, mapping error after change pk field to int and table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity

I tried to change primary key of user table and map it to another names 
whenever i mapped  to string pk no problem but it gives below error with integer pk - AspNetUsers->Id

As i see only ApplicationUser class can not be mapped to AspNetUsers table

below code gives error,

> Invalid object name  'dbo.ApplicationUser1'.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
        CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, 
    //please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
        CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }       

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser,int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("LastName", this.LastName));
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
     int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {          
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("AspNetUsers");                
                c.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.AccessFailedCount,
                    p.Email,
                    p.EmailConfirmed,
                    p.PasswordHash,
                    p.PhoneNumber,
                    p.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
                    p.TwoFactorEnabled,
                    p.SecurityStamp,
                    p.LockoutEnabled,
                    p.LockoutEndDateUtc,`enter code here`
                    p.UserName
                });
            }).HasKey(c => c.Id);
           modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Logins).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Claims).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
           modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);


            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("AspNetLogins");
                c.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.UserId,
                    p.LoginProvider,
                    p.ProviderKey
                });
            }).HasKey(p => new { p.LoginProvider, p.ProviderKey, p.UserId });

            // Mapping for ApiRole
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("AspNetRoles");                
                c.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.Name
                });
            }).HasKey(p => p.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().HasMany(c => c.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId);



            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
                c.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.UserId,
                    p.RoleId
                });
            })
            .HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.RoleId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

                c.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.UserId,
                    p.ClaimValue,
                    p.ClaimType
                });
            }).HasKey(c => c.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best that you can do is not using ASP.NET Identity anymore. They have changed the apis and procedures a dozen of times, and the result is a huge pile of overengineered stuff that you have to override, inherit, etc. in order to do the minimal change to their default implementation... Good luck!

Comment: any solution so, far ?

Answer (score 0):

well, i found the solution. change the mappings in your `OnModelCreating()` method with this code.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomApplicationUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

Hope this helps someone. if it does not please let me know, i might be helpful. :)